# How to resize an image in a Word document?

Tags: excel, vba, image, ms-word, resize

From Excel, open a Word document, paste an image at the current location and then resize it.

I tried using the Height command at the end of the `InlineShapes.AddPicture`.

Here is the code that inserts the image.

```vb
Sub CreateWordDocWithPicture()
    Dim wdApp As Word.Application
    Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
    DocDirectory = "C:\Documents\"
    Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application") 'Create an instance of word
    Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(DocDirectory & "Template.docx", ReadOnly:=True) 
    'Open word file
    wdApp.Visible = True
    wdApp.Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture Filename:=DocDirectory & "Image.jpg", LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True
        
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example:

```
Sub CreateWordDocWithPicture()
Dim wdApp As New Word.Application, wdDoc As Word.Document, wdIshp As Word.InlineShape
Const DocDirectory As String = "C:\Documents\"
With wdApp
  .Visible = True
  'Open word file
  Set wdDoc = .Documents.Open(DocDirectory & "Template.docx", ReadOnly:=True)
  With wdDoc
    'Insert the image
    Set wdIshp = .InlineShapes.AddPicture(FileName:=DocDirectory & "Image.jpg", _
      LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True, Range:=.Range.Characters.Last)
    'Resize the image
    With wdIshp
      .LockAspectRatio = True
      .Height = InchesToPoints(1.5)
    End With
  End With
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much.  I spent so much time on that and just couldn't get the syntax quite right.